# Received less ETH in Bittrex

Tags: exchanges, coinbase

I sent 0.1 ETH from Coinbase to Bittrex. The total transaction in Coinbase is 0.100441 ETH. I guess the difference is for the fees.

But the odd thing is I didn't receive 0.1 in Bittrex. I only got 0.09715353 ETH.

Here is the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x09c0097dc0abd1e6abb406572788502aba8a4769ead93c6d744626cf54763014

Can anybody explain to me what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Bitrex takes a 0.25% commission on all trades. [source](https://bittrex.com/fees)

```
0.1 ETH * 0.975 (bitrex lets you keep) = 0.0975 ETH
```